# Make a call from website

Tags: php, jquery, xml, wordpress

I am developing a website that allow user to make a call from website to the business owner.
I am stuck in a problem that how do i do it. I want to open a Skype window(audio call) or anything by clicking on call now button. (calling external protocol or call exe)
and as it is a responsive website, user can call and send sms from mobile/iphone.
on mobile site, after clicking call button, call should be made from mobile and after clicking sms button,  sms writting window should be open.
pls help me!
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate Skype button on [this website](http://www.skype.com/en/features/skype-buttons/create-skype-buttons/).

Call by phone link has format:

```
 <a href="tel:+435555555">Call me</a>
```

Send SMS link:

```
<a href="sms:+435555555?body=Hallo">Send sms</a>
```

You should test it on devices and maybe hide some of them if you are sure they are not supported.